# Let $f(u)=\tan(u)$ and $g(x)=x^8$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have solved the following:

$$f'(u)=\sec^2(u)$$

$$g'(x)=8x^7$$

However, these two have been giving me issues. This is my progress so far:

$$f(g(x))=\tan(u)^8$$

$$f'(g(x))=\sec^{10}(u)$$

Where did I go wrong here? Also, how would I go about in solving the following (I would just want the first step, not the solution, so I can work it out myself):

$$(f \circ g)'(x)$$

UPDATE - Ty, $\sec^{10}(u)$ was just a guess. Could you let me know where I went wrong here?

Comment: Where did you get $\sec^{10} u$ from..?  Also, don't forget the constants of integration.

Comment: To start, $f(g(x)) = f(x^8) = tan(x^8)$ and $f'(g(x))=f'(x^8)=sec^2(x^8)$. Do it slower. Then for $(f \circ g)'$ you want to use the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write $\tan(x)^8$ it's not clear whether you mean $\tan(x^8)$ or $(\tan x)^8.$

But if $f(x)= \tan x$ and $g(x) = x^8,$ then $f(g(x)) = \tan (x^8).$

The chain rule is differentiation by substitution.
\begin{align}
& y = \tan u, & & u = x^8 \\[8pt]
& \frac{dy}{du} = \sec^2 u, & & \frac{du}{dx} = 8x^7
\end{align}
And then:
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx} & = \big(\sec^2 u\big)\cdot 8x^7 \\[10pt]
& = \big( \sec^2 (x^8)\big)\cdot 8x^7.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

$f^{\prime}(\color{red}{u}) = \sec^2(\color{red}{u})$, so $f^{\prime}(\color{red}{g(x)}) = \sec^2(\color{red}{g(x)}) = \sec^2(\color{red}{x^8})$.

The chain rule states that
$$(f \circ g)^{\prime}(x) = f^{\prime}(g(x)) \cdot g^{\prime}(x)\text{.}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note $$f(g(x)) = \tan (g(x)) = \tan (\color{red}{x^8}) \ne \tan (u)^8 $$ Now, to find $(f\circ g)’(x)$, use the chain rule, while remembering that the derivative of $\tan x$ is $\sec^2x$ and the derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$.